# Laravel Dusk Can't Read Click of Undefined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I tried simple demo of laravel dusk but I get the following error; I tried to update composer installer as suggested by some solution and also tried to set duskcommand.php as suggested on git but still having the error.

> Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.
> PHPUnit 7.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> [1004/130622.087:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
>
> 1. Tests\Browser\RegisterTest::testExample
>    Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
>    (Session info: headless chrome=69.0.3497.100)
>    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

I'm trying this demo in Windows 10.

below is my RegisterTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class RegisterTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function ($browser) {
            $browser->visit('/') //Go to the homepage
                    ->clickLink('Register') //Click the Register link
                    ->assertSee('Register') //Make sure the phrase in the argument is on the page
            //Fill the form with these values
                    ->value('#name', 'Joe') 
                    ->value('#email', 'joe@example.com')
                    ->value('#password', '123456')
                    ->value('#password-confirm', '123456')
                    ->click('button[type="submit"]') //Click the submit button on the page
                    ->assertPathIs('/home') //Make sure you are in the home page
            //Make sure you see the phrase in the argument
                    ->assertSee("You are logged in!"); 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the result of `$browser->visit('/')->dump();`.